# Jar file is not working, I get error: Invalid jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me

I am very new to J2ME. I am creating an J2ME application using Eclipse. I exported the .jar file from the project. But when I am trying to open that .jar file in mobile phones, it's giving "Invalid jar file " error. This is working on emulator properly.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Some phone needs JAD as well, have you installed JAD file as well ?

Comment: Yeah, I did that also..so for jad its giving error: "compulsory attributes missing"

Comment: do you have `MIDlet-Jar-URL` attribute in JAD?

Comment: @mr_lou,I tried with different phones of Nokia(Asha 305,Nokia e5 etc)

Comment: I recently experienced that too with Nokia phones. Strangely, after removing all Nokia specific JAD/MANIFEST attributes from the MANIFEST, the JAR installed fine. One would think Nokia could figure out to just ignore attributes they don't support - especially if we're talking attributes they invented themselves, but apparently no. Anyway, that's my only guess at this time. Remember to remove them from both the JAD and MANIFEST.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not specified compulsory attributes like midlet-class-name
you can specify this by open application descriptor.
Better way to create jad/jar file is 
Right Click onProject->J2ME->create package